# Dont get the text too look the right way

Tags: html, css, image

**What I want:**

1: 
 What I want is that the `echo '<span class="badge bg-red">Denied</span>';` is directly under the `echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '</b></a>';` and that the `img` is the full height. And if I use the `<br>` it puts the text under the img and not next to it. Because I need the image to be always on the left with the text next to it.

2: The second thing that I want is that there is a small line under the

`echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '</b></a>'; 
echo '<a> - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . '</a>';`

How it looks like now.
[image]

The code:

```
       <div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title"><b>Topics</b></h3>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->          

<div class="box-body">
   <?php
    $toppic = $app->get_topics();
    foreach($toppic as $topic){
     echo '<div id="topic">';
     if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { 
        echo '<img style="height:100%;"class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id']src="###.'/'.$topic['foto'].'"###'" />';
     } else {
        echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
     }
       echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '.$topic['topicnaam'].'<$####'</b></a>'; 
       echo '<a> - ' . $topic['voornaam'] ####. " " . $topic['achternaam']#### . '</a>';
       echo '<span style="float:right;"class="fa-stack"><span class="fa fa-comment-o fa-stack-2x"></span><strong class="fa-stack-1x" style="font-size:10px;">999</strong></span>';
       echo '<span class="badge bg-red">Denied</span>';
       echo '</div>';
    }
  ?>
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer text-center">
    </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
```

The custom css:

```
#topic a {
    color: black;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#topic {
    padding: 10px;
}

#topic i{
    font-size: 2.3em;
    width: 33px;
}
```

Comment: you have an error here `echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '.$####'</b></a>';` you open a `<b>` and close it in the the `<a>`. The correct form is `echo '<a href="https://####/reactie"> <b>'.$####'</b></a>';` Also you have some `php` closure but I don't see where the `php` is opened

Comment: Also I would suggest to make fiddle with static data in order to proper inspect your issue

Comment: You removed a lot from the source, so that it's now no longer valid PHP. This makes your question difficult to follow. (For example, you want something under the "voornaam", but there is no "voornaam" in the source.) Maybe it would help to provide us with a mocked-up screenshot of what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: @MrLister I added the PHP thought ill leave it because it doesnt matter with the lay out?

Comment: @Sabbin Added the php for this to the question

Comment: Can you do a fiddle with static data? a mock-up in order to proper inspect the css?

Comment: @Sabbin https://jsfiddle.net/tdstvegd/1/ this is the fiddle from the person down below it works good but now I want a line under the text (in this case: "Title") that keeps going to the end and not stop when the word stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the alternatives is by using the list tag
Here is an example for your convenience:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" class="pic">
</li>
<li>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>description declined</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.pic{
  max-width:150px;
  max-height:150px;
  margin-right:50px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```css
.pic{
  max-width:150px;
  max-height:150px;
  margin-right:50px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" class="pic">
</li>
<li>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>description declined</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Adjust it accordingly with your code. Have fun :)

Comment: Hello thx! Do you also know how to get a line under the title and the line needs to not only be under it but also until the end of the line. @Squish

Comment: No problem, Just add a <hr> tag below the title and adjust the length accordingly with a new css. - @maybeiforgotmypassword

Comment: is their no other way to do it?

Comment: using the <hr> tag is usually the simplest way, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I want the line to be close to the text because now it is just like a `<br>` and I want the text to be closer to eachother

Comment: In that case you can play with the paddings and margins in the css :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's some sintax errors at the php code in the `<div class="box-body">`, check it out because the compiler can throw an error.

At the css part, i would use `position: relative` to the DOM elements inside the `<div class="topic">` and later adjust it with `top, bottom, left, right` (Check [this out](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more info about the positioning properties in css).
Also, i would set the image full height with `height: 100%`, but, just as a recommendation, try using `height: auto`, with this property the img height adjusts to the DOM and it MAYBE get a height you like([Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) some info about height property).

Finally, you could get the small line with the `<u>` html tag or with the css `text-decoration: underline`. You can see both [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp).

Hope this answer helps you, if it does, please vote it up so that people can get helped if needed :)

Comment: Hello Alex thx for this! I will take a look at it! The only thing I already see is that you want me to use `<u>` te problem is that the line need to be there until the "reaction cloud with 999 in it" so not just underr the text

Comment: @maybeiforgotmypassword Then i would use the `<hr>` tag inside the div and to position it with the mentioned properties